# FAB inside FrameLayout to be on top of fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout, floating-action-button

In my layout I have a `FrameLayout` in which I intend to display different layouts depending on user input. I want to display a `FloatingActionButton` in all those layouts.

In order to not repeat the `FloatingActionButton` in all of them, I want to have it attached to the `FrameLayout`. The problem is that the button is not displayed correctly on top of the `fragment` layout. For example, the initial `fragment` displayed, has a `GridView` and the button is behind it.

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categories_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/categories_listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainPane"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the `fragment` layout displayed programmatically:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/productsGridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:numColumns="3"></GridView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Are all your fragments on the same Activity? If so, you could add it on the Activity layout so it always stays on top of the FrameLayout.

Comment: Yes, they are all in MainActivity and this is it's layout

Comment: Where are you inflating the fragment? in the `FrameLayout` `mainPane` ?

Comment: yes, inside my MainActivity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `FrameLayout`, declare another `Framelayout` and inflate the fragment there. It should work.

```
... <LinearLayout>
     .....

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainPane"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_inflate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this, so that the FAB and the fragment don't share the same FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categories_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/categories_listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainPane"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this places the FAB at the bottom left corner of the screen. I wanted it on the bottom left corner of the `FrameLayout` which is only 3/4 of the screen

Answer (score 1):

add FAB inside the framelayout without using coordinativelayout

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/drawer_foot" >
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/shareFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

find your framelayout and call this methord and pass your frame layout in this method 100% it will work

```
    private void addFloatingButton(FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    int i20 = 20;
    int i50 = 50;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams clFloatingButtonParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(i50, i50);
    clFloatingButtonParams.setMargins(0, 0, i20, i20);
    clFloatingButtonParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
    FloatingActionButton clFloatingActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
    clFloatingActionButton.setId(R.id.calander_view_fab);
                 frameLayout.addView(clFloatingActionButton, clFloatingButtonParams);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ***layout_gravity*** to the FAB, and then you can set it in any corner you want.

**For Setting at right bottom:**

```
android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
```

**For Setting at left bottom:**

```
android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
```

**For Setting at left top:**

```
android:layout_gravity="left|top"
```

**For Setting at right top:**

```
android:layout_gravity="right|top"
```